# can we stream WAV audio format

Tags: iphone, wav, audio-streaming

Can we stream live audio which is in **WAV format** from iPhone to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes. Yes, we can.**

I use DNLA applications very often to stream media to/from my devices (iPhone, iPod, Android, Laptop) and a server in my home.  The WAV format is most certainly supported among many others.

[You can read up on DNLA here.](http://www.dlna.org/about_us/about/) It's an organization that outlines a set of interoperability guidelines that allow servers and clients to stream various formats of media.  I love it.

There is no shortage of DNLA compatible apps for both the iPhone and Android.  On my wife's iPhone, I use the free version of [iMediaShare](http://www.bianor.com/ims/).

And on my Android, I use [AndroMote](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.czesla-android-remote-wnp.aspx).

Now, if you want to know how to do this as a developer, I have no idea since I don't write for the iPhone.  However, the answer to your actual question is "Yes," it can be done and there are plenty of apps that do it via the DLNA or Universal Plug N Play (UPnP) guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for information. Can i also downstream the same format from server to iPhone.what is .ts format?

Comment: Yes. It works in both directions. TS files usually store DVD video.  Some players like VLC can playback TS files directly.  For more info on TS go here: http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/ts